# Count the number of times an index exists using a query containing multiple EXIST() statements

Tags: mysql, search, indexing, counting

My query gets the results of these products based on if they exist in a separate table index. I am trying to get a count of all the instances where they exist so I can ORDER the results by relevance. Everything I try seems to return the variable @priority as 0. Any ideas?

Maybe it is better to use join statements?

Thank you for your help.  Here is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT  `products` . * , @priority
    FROM  `products`
    LEFT JOIN productstypes_index ON productstypes_index.product_id = products.id
WHERE (

EXISTS (

SELECT *
    FROM  `productstypes_index`
    WHERE  `productstypes_index`.`product_id` =  `products`.`id`
    AND  `productstypes_index`.`_type_id` =  '1'
)
AND (
(
(

EXISTS (

SELECT @priority := COUNT( * )
    FROM  `producthashtags_index`
    WHERE  `producthashtags_index`.`product_id` =  `products`.`id`
    AND  `producthashtags_index`.`producthashtag_id` =  '43'
)
)
AND (

EXISTS (

SELECT @priority := COUNT( * )
    FROM  `producthashtags_index`
    WHERE  `producthashtags_index`.`product_id` =  `products`.`id`
    AND  `producthashtags_index`.`producthashtag_id` =  '11'
)
)
)
)
)
ORDER BY  `updated_at` DESC;
```

Comment: MySQL ignores the SELECT list in EXISTS subquery, so it makes no difference what you type in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do without those `exists`, and without variables. Also, a `left join` has no sense if you have an `exists` condition on the joined table. Then you might as well do the more efficient `inner join` and put the extra type condition in the join condition.

The priority can be calculated by a count over the hash tags, but only those with `id in ('43', '11')`.

```
SELECT     products.* 
           count(distinct producthashtags_index.producthashtag_id) priority
FROM       products
INNER JOIN productstypes_index 
        ON productstypes_index.product_id = products.id
       AND productstypes_index._type_id =  '1'
INNER JOIN producthashtags_index 
        ON producthashtags_index.product_id = products.id
       AND producthashtags_index.producthashtag_id in ('43', '11')
GROUP BY   products.id  
ORDER BY   updated_at DESC;
```

Comment: I think you are on to something, but my index table, producthashtags_index, doesn't have an id.

Comment: Hey trincot, don't I need to join the producthashtag_index somewhere here? 

I get an error:
Unknown column 'producthashtags_index.producthashtag_id' in 'field list'

Comment: Can a product have the same `producthashtag_id` in `producthashtags_index` multiple times? If so, what makes the distinction? In the mean time I updated my answer.

Comment: I actually just added a primary key index, producthashtags_index.id

Comment: Ah, in that case use that instead in the `count`. You may want to play with removing/adding `distinct` in the count: it depends how you want to count and give priority.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL ignores the SELECT list in EXISTS subquery, so it makes no difference what you type in there. This is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

An approach using joins would look like below:

```
SELECT p.id, 
       COUNT(case when phi.product_id is not null then 1 end) AS instances
FROM products p
INNER JOIN productstypes_index  pti ON pti.product_id = p.id AND pti.`_type_id` = 1
LEFT JOIN producthashtags_index phi ON phi.product_id = p.id AND phi.producthashtag_id IN (11,43)
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY instances DESC;
```

I have removed additional backticks where I believe they are not neccessary and also if your `id` columns in tables are integers, you do not need quotation marks.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for your edit. Copy paste aliases... :)

Comment: As per the other solution, I think I need a unique ID for my index tables.

Comment: This doesn't seem to pull them accurately for some reason, however, I do think joining is the correct way to go. This seems to pull products with productstypes_index type_id = 1 and ignore the hashtag index requirements.

Comment: Sorry I send that last message before your edit. Thanks, I will take a look!

Comment: What is the LEFT JOIN with `productstypes_index` table good for?

Comment: I've simplified the query.